# Service Fabric Cluster Upgrade While it is Running

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I setup a cluster in my production environment with 3 VMs and setup some applications there. Now if I open the explorer, I got a warning in the cluster

> Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.UpgradeOrchestrationService',
>   Property='ClusterVersionSupport', HealthState='Warning',
>   ConsiderWarningAsError=false. The current cluster version 5.4.164.9494
>   support ends 6/10/2017 12:00:00 AM. Please view available upgrades
>   using Get-ServiceFabricRegisteredClusterCodeVersion and upgrade using
>   Start-ServiceFabricClusterUpgrade.

My application is till running there.

I didn't update the cluster so far. I have a question that, can we directly update the cluster without unregistering the applications? will it have any impact on the already running application while we updating the cluster configuration?

Thanks,
Divya

Comment: Yes, you can upgrade the cluster while your apps are running.

Answer (score 0):

As @LodeRunner28 stated, you can upgrade the cluster version while it is running, and actually in Azure you can setup your cluster to allow it to be updated automatically as new versions of Service Fabric are available.